# Derivative of a definite integral with two constraints

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am new to this, and I want to see if I have the right answer:

> $$\frac{d}{dx}\int^{2x}_{x} s^2 ds = \int^{0}_{x} + \int^{2x}_{0}= -\int^{x}_{0}+\int^{2x}_{0} =-x^2+8x^3   $$

Comment: You're close. But nothing should be cubed at the end of the day.

Comment: @mixedMath Hmm... is this not one of the steps?$$-x^2(1)+(2x)^2*2x$$

Comment: The second term should be $(2x)^2(2)$.

Comment: AHHHH!!! derivative of 2x is 2!

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to evaluate integral here so$$\int^{2x}_{x} s^2 ds=\left[\frac{s^3}{3}\right]_x^{2x}=\frac{7x^3}{3}$$

> $$\frac{d}{dx}\int^{2x}_{x} s^2 ds = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{7x^3}{3}=7x^2$$

---

and Using  [Leibniz Integral Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html)

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}p(s,x)\,\mathrm ds=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\,\mathrm ds+p(b(x),x)\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}-p(a(x),x)\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}$$

put $p(s,x)=s^2\quad,a(x)=x\quad,b(x)=2x$ to get

$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}\int^{2x}_{x} s^2 ds &= \int_{x}^{2x}0\,\mathrm ds+p(2x,x)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}2x-p(x,x)\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}x\\
&= 0+2\cdot(2x)^2-1\cdot x^2\\
\end{align}$$

> $$\frac{d}{dx}\int^{2x}_{x} s^2 ds =7x^2$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

In a most compact form, you can write the fundamental theorem of calculus as $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(s) \, ds=f\big(b(x)\big) b'(x)-f\big(a(x)\big) a'(x)$$

Comment: will that compact form applies if question is like $$
f(x)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{2t} \int_{x-t}^{x+t} s f'(s) ds
$$

Comment: @SophieClad. You can notice that $\int s~f'(s)~ ds=s~f(s)-\int f(s)~ds$

Comment: Sorry i couldn't get your point . how can above question be done with compact form